# how to print arrray number and its value

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```

How to print this array in this format.

> 1:2 
>        hello:2
>        world:1

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) is for:

```
$variable = [1=>2, 'hello'=>2, 'world'=>1];

foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key:$value ";
}
```

Prints:

> 1:2 hello:2 world:1